# Creating test method stub in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2012

Before i installed resharper i could create a [TestMethod] stub by writing testm and tab 2 times. Is there a way to still do this while having resharper installed? 
I am using Visual Studio 2012 with visual studio test tools.

Answer (score 1):

`testm` is a code Snippet of VS.

Visual Studio code snippets for C# are automatically imported into ReSharper as live templates. That means you can invoke any code snippet by pressing Ctrl+J.